# How to use switch with integer 0 in PHP?

Tags: php, comparison-operators

having the integer 0 as switch parameter will take the first result "foo":

```
$data=0; // $data is usually coming from somewhere else, set to 0 here to show the problem
switch ($data) :
    case "anything":
        echo "foo";
        break;
    case 0:
        echo "zero";
        break;
    default: 
        echo "bar";
endswitch;
```

How do I change this, so the switch will write "zero" as expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The switch/case statement uses loose comparison, and, like it or not, `0 == "anything"` is `true`:

> [**Comparison Operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
>
> [...] If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch
>   statement. [...]
>
> ```
> var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
> ```

One solution is to change all case statements to string, and do a string comparison:

```
$data = 0;
switch ((string) $data): ## <- changed this
    case "anything":
        echo "foo";
        break;
    case "0":            ## <- and this
        echo "zero";
        break;
    default: 
        echo "bar";
endswitch;
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch/case statement uses "loose-comparison" (i.e. `==`. in this case, `0` also means `false` and `1` also means `true`. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)

To avoid this problem, two solutions:

1) As suggested by @zzlalani, add quotes.

```
   case '0': ...
```

2) Explicitly cast the switch statement to force a strict comparison (`===`)

```
    switch((string)($data)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
$data=0;
switch ($data)
{
    case 0:
        echo "bar";
        break;
    default: 
        echo "foo";
    break;
}
```

EDIT :

> How do I change this, so the switch will write "zero" as expected?

### You need to move your case statement above.

```
$data=0;
switch ($data) :
    case 0:            // Moved this case to the begining
        echo "zero";
        break;

    case "anything":
        echo "foo";
        break;
    default: 
        echo "bar";
endswitch;
```

This is because **`switch`** does not do a "**strict-type**" checking.

Comment: LOL! the problem is not to just write "bar"

Comment: Why did you change your question ? This answer will be invalid then ?

Comment: I didn't change it, I just clarified the problem with integer 0, (see the title)

Comment: now what if the $data changes to anything `$data='anything';`